# Can I add a few completely new tags to the YouTrack issue using single command window?

Tags: command, youtrack

Like the title says, is it possible to add a few completely new tags to the issue using single command window?
I tried e.g. `tag test1 tag test2` but command preview sees this as one command `1. Add new tag test1 tag test2`. It looks like I need some kind of text separator, but I cannot find it in documentation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not possible. 
In case of 'tag' command it will try first to find existing tag and in if there is no such tag it will create one from entire string.